# using sendto() in iPhone - memory allocation issue

Tags: iphone

i was using lib to send RTP packets. after session was established, on bad quality networks i have received this error for most packets, which was send:

```
2012-02-26 05:15:53.947[492:7c3b] iovlen size:12 
2012-02-26 05:15:53.950[492:7c3b] iovlen size:160 
2012-02-26 05:15:53.955[492:7c3b] Error sending rtp packet: Cannot allocate memory ; socket=26
```

Probably sockets for iPhone on gprs have some specific issues?
In bellow code i have produces that error:

```
static int rtp_sendmsg(int sock,mblk_t *m, struct sockaddr *rem_addr, int addr_len){
    int error;
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct iovec iov[MAX_IOV];
    int iovlen;
    for(iovlen=0; iovlen<MAX_IOV && m!=NULL; m=m->b_cont,iovlen++){
        iov[iovlen].iov_base=m->b_rptr;
        iov[iovlen].iov_len=m->b_wptr-m->b_rptr;
        //ortp_warning ("iovlen size:%d",m->b_wptr-m->b_rptr);
    }
    if (iovlen==MAX_IOV){
        ortp_error("Too long msgb, didn't fit into iov, end discarded.");
    }
    msg.msg_name=(void*)rem_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen=addr_len;
    msg.msg_iov=&iov[0];
    msg.msg_iovlen=iovlen;
    msg.msg_control=NULL;
    msg.msg_controllen=0;
    msg.msg_flags=0;
    error=sendmsg(sock,&msg,0);
    return error;
}
```

Anybody can suggest to refactor this code (i'm not very strong in C, so final peace of code appreciated) ,this function was called from this part of code:

```
int
rtp_session_rtp_send (RtpSession * session, mblk_t * m)
{
    int error;
    int i;
    rtp_header_t *hdr;
    struct sockaddr *destaddr=(struct sockaddr*)&session->rtp.rem_addr;
    socklen_t destlen=session->rtp.rem_addrlen;
    ortp_socket_t sockfd=session->rtp.socket;

    hdr = (rtp_header_t *) m->b_rptr;
    /* perform host to network conversions */
    hdr->ssrc = htonl (hdr->ssrc);
    hdr->timestamp = htonl (hdr->timestamp);
    hdr->seq_number = htons (hdr->seq_number);
    for (i = 0; i < hdr->cc; i++)
        hdr->csrc[i] = htonl (hdr->csrc[i]);

    if (session->flags & RTP_SOCKET_CONNECTED) {
        destaddr=NULL;
        destlen=0;
    }

    if (rtp_session_using_transport(session, rtp)){
        error = (session->rtp.tr->t_sendto) (session->rtp.tr,m,0,destaddr,destlen);
        //ortp_warning ("rtp_session_using_transport passed");
    }else{
        //ortp_warning ("rtp_session_using_transport NOT passed");

#ifdef USE_SENDMSG
        error=rtp_sendmsg(sockfd,m,destaddr,destlen);
#else
        if (m->b_cont!=NULL)
            msgpullup(m,-1);
        error = sendto (sockfd, (char*)m->b_rptr, (int) (m->b_wptr - m->b_rptr),
             0,destaddr,destlen);
#endif
    }
    if (error < 0){
        if (session->on_network_error.count>0){
            rtp_signal_table_emit3(&session->on_network_error,(long)"Error sending RTP packet",INT_TO_POINTER(getSocketErrorCode()));
        }else ortp_warning ("Error sending rtp packet: %s ; socket=%i", getSocketError(), sockfd);
        session->rtp.send_errno=getSocketErrorCode();
    }else{
        update_sent_bytes(session,error);
    }
    freemsg (m);
    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cannot allocate memory` occurs a lot when using sendto() on iOS when on a dodgy network. I've seen it loads. Basically, there's not a lot you can do about it apart from fail gracefully and perhaps push less through during periods of this problem occurring. It'll be because the buffers are filling up inside the network card.

As for the refactoring - perhaps post that on [code review.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)